# Why do I get "Connection Refused" with nc and curl when accessing google?

Tags: macos, curl, networking, netcat

I have a MacBook Pro running the latest Big Sur OS. This laptop has several accounts. On **one** of these accounts, and **only** on the terminal, I get connection refused errors while trying to curl http://www.google.com and https://www.google.com or any other server.

I also verified this behavior with nc and openssl s_connect. On this account, the browser works fine.

I know the problem isn't the remote server (google is obviously working). I know that it isn't the local networking because other accounts work and even the failing account with a browser works. We have no proxies. I checked with **env** and verified that there is no errant HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY.

In the Mac networking properties I also verified that there are no proxies enabled.

I ran trace route and verified that DNS resolution and the path to the google server is working correctly.

I can also ping the server, so ICMP packets are getting through.

At this point, I'm at a loss. I can only imagine there is **some** kind of process interfering with TCP packets, but I don't know what it could be. This is my son's account, and he's learning to program, so I fear any kind of situation may be at play including some malware. Has anyone faced this before? What steps would you further recommend to find the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this on a child account with Screen Time set to restrict adult websites.

I switched it to unlimited websites and nothing changed so I rebooted and curl started working again.  I then changed it back to restrict adult websites and rebooted and curl kept on working.

I would love a much better answer.

Edit: I was testing with `curl -vvv https://www.office.com`